# How to shift a column by each index in multiIndex?

Tags: pandas

I want to shift a column, but do this for each index in multiindex. For example, I have

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])]

np.random.seed(42)

s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays, columns=['column1'])
```

I want to do something like this:

```
s['column2'] = s['column1'].shift()
```

But it gives me dataframe with a row with NaN only in the first row but I need NaN also in the fifth row.

Comment: `s.groupby(level=0).shift()`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Also, do you know whether it is possible to sort the dataframe for exactly this operation, but keep the order afterwards?